# can a class with non-const constructor be a widget's child? for example a State object being a child of Center or materialApp

Tags: flutter, dart, statefulwidget

i tried to pass a State object to Counter widget as a child, I get the following error:-

Error compiling to JavaScript:
/tmp/dartpadWVXESU/lib/main.dart:59:18: Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is expected.
Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'.
child: _CounterState(),

can anyone please explain me what is happening and why.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _CounterState(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

_CounterState is a class extending State class

Comment: Please provide a minmial example of your code.

Comment: @quoci, I added a snippet

Comment: can you include full sample snippet, here `_CounterState` is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `_CounterState()` is probably not a `StatefulWidget` nor a `StatelessWidget`.

Perhaps your `_CounterState()` definition looks like :

```
class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
...
}
```

You can't pass any type of class to a child of a built in Widget in Flutter.

You can only pass in the instance of a class which extends or implements a `Widget` class.

Comment: thank you @Sushan Shakya, only objects of type 'Widget?' can be passed as a child.